# Invocar método estático genérico con clase genérica

Tags: java

Estoy intentando crear un método estático parametrizado. Tengo este código:

```
class F<T> {
    static <T> void visualizar(Collection<T> lista) {
        for (T elem: lista) {
            System.out.println(elem);
        }
    }
}
```

Como puedo invocar este método porque algo así no funciona:

```
public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        F<Integer> f = new F<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(45);
        integers.add(2);
        F<Integer>.visualizar(integers); // ERROR
    }
}
```

Gracias anticipadas.

Un cordial saludo.

Comment: De primeras es posible que tengas problemas de visibilidad del metodo por ponerlo por defecto.

Answer (score 1):

Así te va a funcionar:

```
F.visualizar(integers);
```

No hay necesidad de poner el tipo, esto sirve cuando vas a crear un objeto (es directiva al compilador). Para ejecutar un método estático no es necesario.